# Get value of column from subquery of pragma_table_info

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm trying to get the value of a row from the query (SQLite):

```
SELECT
(SELECT CAST(name AS TEXT)
FROM pragma_table_info('0')
WHERE CAST(name AS REAL) <= 9
ORDER BY CAST(name AS REAL) DESC
LIMIT 1)
FROM "0"
WHERE "column2" = 'some_sh';
```

The table consists of:

column2, 1, 3, 6, 9 (column names)

a, 20, 30, 40, 50 (data placed)
...

The above query returns to me not '50', but '9', that is, the column name instead of the value. It's like just a part of the query:

```
SELECT CAST(name AS TEXT)
FROM pragma_table_info('0')
WHERE CAST(name AS REAL) <= 9
ORDER BY CAST(name AS REAL) DESC
LIMIT 1) AS column_name
```

without

```
SELECT...FROM "0"
WHERE "column2" = 'some_sh';
```

I don't understand how to extract the value from the row of the found maximum column name (number). It looks correct at first glance, like the query:

```
SELECT "9"
FROM "0"
WHERE "column2" = 'some_sh';
```

Comment: The subquery returns a string literal, not a column name, which can't be used as an identifier in the main SELECT statement.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Can you advise me then what should I use? I don't need a ready-made query, at least tell me through what should I compose the query? I understand how to split it into 2 queries, but how to do it in one query - I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the max value of two or more column values you can use [`MAX()` scalar function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#max_scalar):

```
SELECT MAX(`1`, `3`, `6`, `9`)
FROM `0`
WHERE ....
```

If these columns are nullable, you should use [`COALESCE()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) for each of them:

```
MAX(COALESCE(`1`, 0), COALESCE(`3`, 0), COALESCE(`6`, 0), COALESCE(`9`, 0))
```

Replace `0` with the lowest value that these columns might contain.